# Magento Navigation Bar is not appearing after uploading it to server

Tags: magento, menu, navigation, magento2

I've recently built a Magento Store website using xampp at my local server and after all the build I uploaded it into the server and then tried to start, it does not show the top navigation bar.

I tried adding the categories in the catalog again and reindexing the indexers of Magento using SSH. Also tried to refresh all the cache.

On Localhost:

[Image of Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JixaA.png)

On Server (Hostgator):

[Image of Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8san.png)

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Please show us some code examples of how you've implemented the top navigation bar.

Comment: No Errors but when i was working on localhost navbar is visible but when i go to the server menu bar does not display.

Comment: Please share the implementation and how you are running it on your server

Comment: Hello @Rastalamm, I've tried everything. I started with building a store on XAMPP with all default configurations. Installed a theme and everything was working perfect. When i completed building my web store. I uploaded it to a server. And found the navigation bar (topmenu) dissappeared. I've edited my question and added some images of the UI of the website.  I also have refered some threads like [This thread on magento.stackexchange.com](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239777/topmenu-nav-not-rendering)